# kafka consumer distribute messages to consumers from a single partition | Alternative

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

I have four instances of the application running under a cluster, it means I have four consumers under one consumer group. There would be one single topic with 100's of partition. Now I need to read unique messages from a specific partition using all four consumers. basically I need to distribute messages from specific partition to these four consumers.  If I use **subscribe** then I don't have control to read it from a specific partition and If I use **assign** then I would be receiving the same message across all four consumers.

I agree it is not possible through Kafka, by chance is there any alternative solutions to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already mentioned, it is not possible to "distribute messages from specific partition to these four consumers" as one Kafka partition can only be consumed by at most one consumer of a Consumer Group.

The reference is given in the [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#kafka_mq): "This is achieved by assigning the partitions in the topic to the consumers in the consumer group so that each partition is consumed by exactly one consumer in the group."

As an alternative I suggest to do the following:
Have your KafkaProducer produce the data of interest into a separate Topic with as many partitions you like (to increase throughput). Then have a dedicated application where the number of consumer threads matches the partition of that topic and process the data from there.